# Add Try Catch to Javascripts with SRC

Tags: javascript, html

I have these CODE#1 scripts and the first script has a source that is running on a web service. I need to have a try catch so when the web service goes to a site down, I can make an else condition like in CODE#2. How can I achieve this. Thanks

CODE #1

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://gd.geobytes.com/gd?after=-1&variables=GeobytesCountry,GeobytesCity">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
document.write("<p>Welcome to visitors from "+sGeobytesCity+", " + sGeobytesCountry);
</script>
```

CODE #2

```
TRY
{
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://gd.geobytes.com/gd?after=-1&variables=GeobytesCountry,GeobytesCity">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
document.write("<p>Welcome to visitors from "+sGeobytesCity+", " + sGeobytesCountry);
</script>
}
catch
{
window.location = "geobytes.aspx";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t use try/catch this way. (Especially since you put it outside of the script elements, so it would be part of the HTML code, and HTML is not a programming language and knows no such thing as a try/catch construct.)

But if the first script is supposed to create the variables `sGeobytesCity` and `sGeobytesCountry` that your second script is trying to output, you could check whether they exist or not first in your second script:

```
if(typeof sGeobytesCity !== "undefined") {
  document.write("<p>Welcome to visitors from "+sGeobytesCity+", " +
    sGeobytesCountry);
}
else {
  window.location.href = "geobytes.aspx";
}
```